# Await multiple promises and getting some values from Firebase

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I hope this question is not a duplicate, but I think so. I made a research before posting but the answers I found didn't help me.

I'm using Firebase to save a string content inside the key `myKey` so the structure is something like:

```js
{ myKey: {
    key1: an object stringified,
    key2: an object stringified,
    key2: an object stringified,
    ...

  }
}
```

This is my code:

```js
async fetchContent(documentId, sheetId) {
    const json = await this.fetchSheetContent(documentId, sheetId, 'A:B')

    const content = json.map(async (row) => {
        const stringifiedContent = await readValue(new URL(row.URL).search) // obtain `an object stringified`
        const parsedContent = JSON.parse(stringifiedContent)
        return { row, parsedContent }
      }
    )

    console.log(content) // <-- content is a pending Promise, I want instead an array of objects
    
    // do something with the array of objects
    // return content.map(c => {...) 
}

async function readValue(search) {
  const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(search)
  const key = queryParams.get('myKey')
  if (!key) return
  const stringifiedState = await createSyncContent(STATE_KEY).get(key)
  return stringifiedContent
}

const createSyncContent = (db) => {
  const ref = fbDb.database().ref(db)

  const syncContent = {
    get: async (key) => {
      try {
        const snapshot = await ref.child(key).get()
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          const value = snapshot.val()['myKey']
          return value
        } else {
          console.log('ERROR')
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
      }
    },
  }
  return syncContent
}
```

In that code `content` is a pending Promise, I want instead an array of objects. Where is the error?

Thanks a lot, I'm a beginner in Promises.

---

I tried `Promise.all`:

```js
async fetchContent(documentId, sheetId) {
    const json = await this.fetchSheetContent(documentId, sheetId, 'A:B')

    const content = Promise.all(json.map(async (row) => {
        const stringifiedContent = await readValue(new URL(row.URL).search)
        const parsedContent = JSON.parse(stringifiedContent)
        return { row, parsedContent }
      }
    ))
    
    // do something with the array of objects
    // return content.map(c => {...)
}
```

and:

```js
async fetchContent(documentId, sheetId) {
    const json = await this.fetchSheetContent(documentId, sheetId, 'A:B')

    const content = await json.map(async (row) => {
        const stringifiedContent = await readValue(new URL(row.URL).search)
        const parsedContent = JSON.parse(stringifiedContent)
        return { row, parsedContent }
      }
    )
    
    // do something with the array of objects
    // return content.map(c => {...)
}
```

It seems not to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missing `await`. Try this:

```
const content = await json.map(async (row) => {...})
console.log(content)
```

Comment: Tried but it doesn't work. Typescript warning me `'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.`

Comment: How about this: `content.then(res => console.log(res))` instead of `console.log(content)`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand JS, when you use async before a function, the return type of the function changes to a promise.

**Whats Wrong:**

```
    const content = json.map(async (row) => {
        const stringifiedContent = await readValue(new URL(row.URL).search) // obtain `an object stringified`
        const parsedContent = JSON.parse(stringifiedContent)
        return { row, parsedContent }
      }
    )
```

Here you are using async before map callback function thus the map returns array of pending promises which you see in content.

**Solution (Can be many) :**

You can use Promise.all to run multiple api requests in parallel and wait until all of them are resolved.

Drawback: It will fail if any of the promise fails to resolve.

Workaround: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503872/promise-all-alternative-that-allows-failure)

For Reference : [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

I haven’t tested the answer above. You can try that as well since its short and easy.